# How to get a .csv into a dataframe from gcs with credentials from script?

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

I've been trying to read a bucket in gcs directly into a pandas dataframe like this:

`gcs_df = pandas.read_csv("gs://my_bucket/my_file.csv")`

This results into:

`gcsfs.utils.HttpError: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.`

due to the fact that I haven't set up any credentials in my local machine (from what I read).

For all other features of the scripts I was using a service account via:

`sa_creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("my_sa_key.json")`

Can I somehow pass this info into the read_csv so I won't have to use the account in my local machine?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So `pandas` library depends on the gcsfs library. So to do the above all you have to do is the following:

```
import pandas
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project= <project_id>, token=<json path>)
with fs.open("gs://my_bucket/my_file.csv") as f:
    gcs_df = pandas.read_csv(f)
print(gcs_df)
```

The  refers to the service account credentials saved as key in .json format. Based on [gcsfs docs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it can be a dictionary or more.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but it might still be usefull for someone :
If you have a path to the json file containing your credentials, you can add it to your environment variable from within your code using `os.environ`:

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "my_sa_key.json"
```

Then everything using `gcsfs` should find what are now your default credentials. I tested it to write a csv with pandas and it worked.